# TextInputLayout hint label not expanding after EditText is losing focus

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have a `TextInputLayout` with a `TextInputEditText` inside. The problem I'm facing is that when I click on the edit text and start writing, the hint label of the layout goes on top of the edit text, however when I click on a button (submit for example), the edit text loses focus but the hint label remains on top even though I clear the text on the edit text.

I've tried different solutions I found here, but none seems to work.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/force_focus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_21dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_extra_tiny"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_21dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <LinearLayout>
        …
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="100"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_input"
                android:hint="@{TranslationKeys.input_text_hint}">

                <com.test.ui.widget.MyEditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_text"
                    android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewActions.onTextChanged(text)}"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType=“@{!viewActions.isChecking ? InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS : InputType.TYPE_NULL}"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout>
            …
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my layout, I removed some unrelated views. When I press a certain button, I request focus on `force_focus`.

Comment: Did you try this: Onclick of submit button, if EditText has an empty String, clear focus for that EditText??

Comment: @DeePanShu That's exactly what I'm doing, I'm doing `input.getText().clear();` and requesting focus on a different layout.

Comment: did you used this?? input.clearFocus()

Comment: Of course, I did @DeePanShu

Comment: app:expandedHintEnabled="false" try this and also post relevant code.so one check it. Just paragraph is insufficient.

Comment: You shouldn't use ```input.getText().clear()``` rather ```input.setText("")```. Since it's a TextInputLayout use ```input.getEditText().setText("");```

Comment: @Radhey Wouldn't `app:expandedHintEnabled ="false"` disable the floating hint? I added extra information on my post.

Comment: @Joel that's not the issue here, using either way will do clear the text, but the hint label will remain floating and won't go back to being expanded again.

Comment: Did you add ```android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"``` to your TextInputLayout's EditText and try clearing focus?

Comment: @Joel I believe `clearFocus` isn't needed when another view requests the focus. Which is the case here, but still that doesn't make the ET lose the focus.

Comment: Did you try adding the android:focusable line to your nested TextInputEditText